# Upsample vector by including zeros in-between elements

Tags: arrays, matlab, for-loop, octave

I am trying to make a Upsampling code, so i want to insert a zeros vector inside a vector, like this:

```
z=[0 0]%Zeros Vector
x=[1 2 3 4]%Vector to Upsample
y=[1 0 0 2 0 0 3 0 0 4 0 0]%Vector Upsampled
```

I have this code:

```
fs=20;
N=50;
T=1/fs;
n=0:1:N-1;
L=3;
M=2;
x = exp(-0.5*n*T).*sin(2*pi*n*T);
A=zeros(1,L);
disp(A);
for i = 1:M:length(x)
  x(:,i)=A;

 end
 disp(x);
```

But I am gettinf this error:

```
A(I,J,...) = X: dimensions mismatch
```

Any Idea of how can I do that?

Comment: Which version of MATLAB are you using?

Comment: Please consider accepting one of the answers to indicate the system that your problem is solved. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forget the loop. Use the following solution:

```
out = zeros(1,length(x)*L);
out(:,1:L:end) = x
```

Comment: is `[1 2]:L:end` a typo? I've never seen that before

Comment: I tried on octave, it does nothing. Plus, the code logic tells me nothing different that 1:L:end wouldn't do. What does it do on matlab?

Comment: Oh!! I was actually doing something else before. Yes, that does not do anything here! Let me edit!!

Comment: I'm more surprised it doesn't throw an error to be honest! I wonder if there's a way to exploit this in a hack? :D

Comment: you can even do  `1:[3,4]:100`, or  `[1:5:[100,200]` and it will just ignore all other elements! Fascinating!

Comment: I bet you can create all sorts of different ranges automatically by using matrices and doing circshifts over them! \o/

Comment: hahah, check it out! `a=randi(10,[1,10]); b=randi(10,[1,10]); c=randi(10,[1,10]); for i = 1:9; a:b:c, a(1)=[];b(1)=[];c(1)=[]; end`. Random ranges! awesome! \o/

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using `bsxfun` and `reshape`:

```
y = reshape(bsxfun(@times,[1;z.'],x),1,[]);
```

I initially thought of `repelem`, but decided it was too much work. However, if you just want to make your vector longer using a "zero order approximation" - this is just the function for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `repmat` and `reshape` to get the upsampled vector as:

```
y = reshape([x' repmat(z,size(x,2),1)]',1,[])

y =

    1   0   0   2   0   0   3   0   0   4   0   0
```

Keep in mind that `z` and `x` are row vectors, you may need to play with the statement a little bit if they are column vectors.

Answer (score 1):

A short alternative using the [**`kron`ecker tensor product**](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/kron.html):

```
y = kron(x,[1, z])     %// x(:).' and z(:).' for independent vector orientations
```

And another fast alternative:

```
y = [1; z(:)]*x; y = y(:).'       %// x(:).' for independent vector orientations
```

which is basically equivalent to:

```
y = reshape( [1; z(:)]*x, 1, [])  %// x(:).' for independent vector orientations
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `upsample`

```
fs=20;
N=50;
T=1/fs;
n=0:1:N-1;
L=3;
x = exp(-0.5*n*T).*sin(2*pi*n*T);

x = upsample(x, L)
```

Comment: don't forget to add a note that use of `upsample` is not a function of Matlab proper. It is part of the control toolbox.